# Is it possible to write a batch file to assign shortcutkey to a .jar file in Windows

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

as explained in my question, yupp, I'm looking for a yes/no answer to it, if possible could someone direct me to a way to do so?

Basically, I'm aware of the thread "[How to set up keyboard shortcuts from windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320268/how-to-set-up-keyboard-shortcuts-from-windows-command-line)" but nircmd's shortcutkey cmd as suggested in the thread isn't working so i'm looking for an alternative to do so.

*TO CLARIFY*
Do note that I'm aware of the manual way to assign a shortcutkey in windows like clicking into properties and setting it, but i'm looking for a cmd line or .bat way :) THANKS!

Do advise :) thanks in advance!!!

Comment: _"shortcutkey cmd as suggested in the thread isn't working"_. What's the problem?

Comment: Why not a [tag:java-web-start] shortcut?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Hi!, after typing one of the example 

- nircmd.exe cmdshortcutkey "c:\temp" "Turn Monitor Off" "Ctrl+Shift+M" monitor off

when i press the hotkey the monitor didn't turn off, but upon clicking on the shortcut itself it works. Thus showing that the shortcutkey wasn't working, I've email nircmd regarding that but hasn't got a reply thus i'm asking on stackoverflow

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: @trashgod our project disallow connection to the internet

Comment: @user3885195 OK, understood. I don't know about nircmd but you can do it without any 3rd party tool simply using few VBScript lines (see answer posted below).

Comment: @CodeObelisk: None is required; local host or intranet is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it directly using `cmd.exe` commands (without 3rd party tools) but you can create a small VBScript script for that.

Methods for Shell interoperability are in the ActiveX object [`WScript.Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99(v=vs.84).aspx) and method you need is [`CreateShortcut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys(v=vs.84).aspx):

```
Shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
link = Shell.CreateShortcut("Shortcut file name.lnk");
link.TargetPath = "path to your program";
link.Arguments = "program arguments";
link.Description = "shortcut description";
link.Hotkey = "CTRL+SHIFT+M";
link.Save();
```

Save this code in a file .vbs file and execute it once, it'll create your shortcut and it'll be available immediately. Note that there are more properties you can set (icon, window style, working directory and so on), just refer to MSDN for [`WshShortcut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6kst2k(v=vs.84).aspx) object documentation.

Comment: Wow! This is awesome!!! Thank u so much!!! Then i can just run the vbs script via my java program! Thats awesome! Will go look into the .vbs script thingy immediately! Thanks!!! I almost had no hope to this being a tiny feature of my project already! Thk u sooooo much!